# SUMPRODUCT with SUMIF

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I currently have this:

`=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(A:A;Index(List;;1);B:B))`

Column A is a list of names, column B is a list of values for each names. The named range List has 2 columns, the first one are names and the second one are boolean values (0 or 1).

My formula actually works to return the sum of every column B values of its corresponding name in the A column IF that name is in the first column of my named range List. It works fine.

However, I would like to filter that to only include names from List that have the boolean value equal to 1 (ie. `Index(List;;2) = 1`.

How is this possible?

This is what I tried but it gives me a #REF! error:

`=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(A:A;Index(List;;1)*Index(List;;2);B:B))`

Comment: When you replaced the commas with semi-colons, I take it you took note of the TWO commas after List?

Comment: Yes, but my problem seems to be with my List. If I do `=INDEX(LIST;60;1)` everything is fine, but as soon as I try another column (replacing the 1 with 2 for example), i get a #REF! error. List is actually `=$B$2:$B$100;$L$2:$W$100` (this is from another sheet, column B being uniques names and all the other columns L:W being 0's or 1's). I thought it would do the same as the B2:W100 range without the C:K columns but it doesn't seem so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably best to switch to an **array formula****:

```
=SUM(SUMIF(A:A,IF(INDEX(List,,2),INDEX(List,,1)),B:B))
```

***Array formulas are not entered in the same way as 'standard' formulas. Instead of pressing just ENTER, you first hold down CTRL and SHIFT, and only then press ENTER. If you've done it correctly, you'll notice Excel puts curly brackets {} around the formula (though do not attempt to manually insert these yourself).*

Comment: It returns 0. I will have to do some more tests to understand why. I had to change every commas for semicolons.

Comment: How does Excel automatically loops through the rows of the List? I don't understand. My A column has for example 100 lines since the same name can be here more than one time, while the first column of List is unique.

Comment: This one makes the most sense to me too!! +1

Answer (score 1):

Since your Named Range consists of discontinous ranges, when INDEXing it you will need to include INDEX's 4th parameter (area_num) in order to clarify which of the ranges ($B$2:$B$100 or $L$2:$W$100) you wish to refer to, e.g.:

```
=INDEX(List,60,1,**2**)
```

which will return the value in cell L61.

Regards

Comment: Does this work with your previous formula? `{=SUM(SUMIF(A:A,IF(INDEX(List,,2, 2),INDEX(List,,1)),B:B))}`

Comment: It always return 0. I tested the Index functions and they are working. I also tested the IF condition and it's working too, my 0's and 1's are correctly interpreted like booleans. Any ideas?

Comment: Got it working from my first formula: `=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(A:A;IF(INDEX(List;;6;2);INDEX(List;;1);0);B:B))`. If not entered as an array formula, it still works but won't check the IF() condition. Why is that? I searched a little bit for array formulas but didn't really find any concrete reason.

Comment: I don't see how this COULD work without array-entry, since, as you say, the IF clause will not be processed. Also, since CSE is required, you may as well change the SUMPRODUCT to SUM.

Comment: I swapped the SUMPRODUCT for SUM, it gives the same result anyway so SUMPRODUCT isn't needed I guess. Thanks a lot for your help, it works perfectly now. I will accept your other answer.